# How to change overall size of mat table

Tags: angular, overflow, mat-table

I am currently unable to get rid of the excess overflow to the right of the table columns.  It is expanding past the end of the normal view width (causing scroll).  I have tried every single thing I could think of so far to no avail.

Comment: Okay, I fixed it.  Hope this saves somebody else the headache. ```.mat-footer-row,
.mat-header-row,
.mat-row {
    display: inline-flex;
    min-width: 85%;
    float:left;
    left:-70px;
}``` and then ```display:block``` in the table{} styling

Comment: Please, mark your question as solved. It is not obvious, that you don't need any further help.

Comment: Will do, command.  Also, the left:-70px is not necessary when these styling properties are applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I fixed it. Hope this saves somebody else the headache. .mat-footer-row, .mat-header-row, .mat-row {     display: inline-flex;     min-width: 85%;     float:left;     } and then display:block in the table{} styling –